# simple encode/decode with PHP to avoid passing id that are easy to guess

Tags: php

is there a "simple" way to mask an interger in PHP?

I have /users/1, /users/2...

I want to have something a little bit more fancier like /users/fsdafs3453 to make it hard to guess user ids. it doesn´t need to be super secure is just to avoid having my users switch from user to user just changing the url. I tried with sha1(...) but there´s no way to decode it. thank you!

Comment: If security isn't an issue, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: What sense is there in making something "a bit secure" by obfuscation? Don't waste your time, instead solve the issue. Your service has to be robust against such attempts to "switch the user".

Answer (score 0):

I have used hashids in some projects. As security is not an issue it works fine in most cases.

https://hashids.org/php/

Another solution a bit more secure is to save a slug or a uid in your database for each user and use this in your request instead of id.